# "Happen to know" meaning

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, phrase-usage, sentence-usage

"Do you happen to know <strike>is</strike> *if* she has a boyfriend?"

What does the above sentence means . I heard those line in the movie 'the social network' and I would like to know when do we use this phrase "happen to know" .

Comment: Sure? Wasn't there *that* instead of *is*?

Comment: No, “that” doesn't fit *at all*; “if” does. For the answer, see [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/133220/happen-to-know-vs-came-to-know-vs-got-to-know-vs-came-across).

Answer (score 5):

> Do you happen to know if she has a boyfriend? (I think there's a mistake, it should be *if* instead of *is*).

*Happen +to infinitive* means *chance to do something or come about*.

*Happen to know* means *do you know by chance?..*

Answer (score 2):

Do you happen to know if she has a boyfriend?

It means the same as "Do you know if she has a boyfriend?", with the only difference that the use of happen in front of the to-infinitive "to know" makes the question a polite request.

You can use happen +  to-infinitive, including to know, to express that something happens or exists by chance.  For examples:

I happen to know his brother.

He happened to have some money.

I never happened to talk to him.

Besides, you can also use happen + to-infinitive to make a polite request. For examples:

Do you happen to know the way to the station?

You don't happen to have any money, do you?

Do you happen to know the time?